# Regular expression to match string only if trailed by a character

Tags: regex, apache

I need help creating a regular expression.
Here are two sample strings:

```
/path/to/file.jpg
/path/to/file.type.jpg
```

Respectively, I'm trying to capture:

```
file.jpg
file.type.jpg
```

But I want to capture the three as separate strings.

```
file,jpg
file,type,jpg
```

Note that I'm not capturing the periods.
I thought something like this could work (excluding the new lines):

```
([a-z]+)\.
[([a-z]+)[\.]{1}]?
([a-z]{3})
```

Guidance would be appreciated.
I'm wondering if there is another modified I would need to use to have it capture it properly.

The above expression errors out, by the way :(

Comment: Why do you have the {1} quantifier after the second \. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use pattern

```
\/([^.]+)\.?([^.]+|)\.([^.]+)$
```

and you will have 3 groups: file, type (which will be empty, if not present) and extension

Answer (score 1):

You can use: `"\/(?:\w+\/)+(\w+)\.?(\w+)?\.(\w+)"` as regex.

Edit: didnt read about not matching dots.

Live [Demo](http://regexr.com?32jto)

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use:
`/(\w+)(\.(\w+))?\.(\w+){3,4}\b`

Then capturing groups 1, 3 and 4 would be your: file(1) type(3) and jpg/png whatever(4)

Groups taken apart:

1. `(\w+)`  - matches word characters 1 or more (equivalent of saying: `{1, }`
2. `(\.(\w+))?` - matches the 3rd group and with a dot in front, and makes the whole group optional ( `?` )
3. `(\w+)` - as gr 1
4. `(\w{3,4})\b` -  matchees 3 or 4 word characters ( `{3,4}` ) and ensures that after those chracters there are no other characters (word end - `\b` - ! if supported !)

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work:

```
/(\w+)\.(\w+)(?:\.(\w+))?$/
```

[Live Demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/qlcVUplDao)